# Determine when Subject has no subscribers

Tags: android, rx-java2

I want to create a broadcast system using PublishSubject, a background task will poll some endpoint and broadcast the result periodically using this Subject. I would like to start the polling when the first subscriber subscribes to the Subject, and stop the polling when there are no more subscribers. If a new subscriber subscribes, polling should resume.

The only function I see that is somewhat related is hasObservers() but it doesn't quite fit my needs, I would like to have callbacks for subscription and unsubscription - on the former I would start polling if not stated, and on the latter I would stop polling if there are no more subscribers; how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a wrapper around a subject that would keep count, but sounds like your problem could be solved with a `ConnectableObservable`. 
Consider this:

```
Observable<PollData> pollData = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                         .flatMap(i -> api.pollData())
                         .share();
```

Using the `share()` operator makes that observable become a `ConnectableObservable` that will start when the first observer subscribes to it, share all emissions with subsequent subscriptions, and automatically stop when it's last observer unsubscribes.
Read more about it [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html).

Comment: I'm having the same problem but my source is definitely a Subject (OP asks about Subject but in your example the source is an Observable). If I do wrap a subject and add a counter, is there any way to decrement the counter? i.e. how can I track number of unsubscribes?

Comment: You can track subscriptions with the `doOnSubscribe` and `doOnDispose` operators